# Any Significance for Equal Expectation and Variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, random-variables

As the title of the question states: given a random variable $X$, is there any significance / interesting corollaries for when $\mathbb{E}[X]=\text{Var}[X]$?

It would be nice to learn some results in general, but I am particularly interested in Gaussian RVs where $\mu=\sigma^2$, for some $\mu > 0$. Thanks!

Comment: Take any random variable (which has finite expectation and variance).  Then note that there is always some constant  $c$ such that $E[X+c]=\text {Var} [X+c]$  And there is a constant $a$ such that $E[ax]=\text {Var}[ax]$. (at least if neither the Variance nor the mean are $0$).  So you can always make them equal by rescaling.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but here is an interesting example of when such comes up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Kac_theorem

Comment: Doubtful seeing as $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ have different dimensions, e.g., if $\mu$ is a quantity in inches then $\sigma^2$ is in square inches, so your equality would depend on the units of measurement used. It might make more sense to ask about $\mu=\sigma$.

Comment: The only interesting situation  I know where this happens is Poisson distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: One point is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and each has this property (they do not need to be identically distributed) then $X+Y$ does too.

Comment: Some simple discrete examples are a fair $7$-sided die (mean and variance $4$) or a uniform selection from $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ (mean and variance $2$), or as a continuous uniform distribution on $[0,6]$ (mean and variance $3$)

Comment: @Henry funny you mention this example of 7-sided dice! Accidentally stumbling across this result was the driving cause behind my inquiry.

Comment: @theoreticalmasterrace And the sum of any number of fair $7$ sided dice will have the same property